# Zend Framework DB update

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Is there something similar to save for the update task?

If I want to save a new record I just do it:
$data_from_post = $_POST;
$newUser = $usersDb->fetchNew();
$newUser->setFromArray($data_from_post);
$newUser->save();

Is there something for the update task?

Thanks and best regard´s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$where = $usersDb->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', data_from_post['id']);
$usersDb->update($data_from_post, $where);
```

Assuming you have a id field in your post array. Basically update takes two params. The update array and a where clause.

see Updating Rows in a Table [in here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had founded here two great ways to do what I want. Best regard´s.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use $newUser->save() but your $newUser needs to be propagated from a $usersDb->find($_POST['id']); instead of a fetchNew(). And, of course, you'll need to update the $newUser with the new values from $_POST after you've instantiated. The save() method checks for modified fields and routes to update() instead of insert();

Comment: Wow, great one, I will try to do it! And can I save an object? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, that's what you're doing in your same $newUser->save();.